# Django Rest Framework upload file and in response show the url without database ref

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload file directly to server with my expected name and trying to give the file url send in response without saving its ref database field.

This is my views:

```
class DocumentUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        return Response(
            status=204
        )
```

I tried to upload with postman and i see no data is saved in my server media folder.

Can anyone help me in this case? I dont want to save the url of the file in database imageField or or FileField, i just want to upload it to save it directly in server and in response, it should send me the url.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the file in memory but not in any specific directory. If you really want to serve the file via API without any database reference, you would need to write it explicitly into your media folder and then add the field manually to your response object. This approach might help guide you to your solution, please note that I did not test it myself.

```py
from django.conf import settings
import os


class DocumentUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_obj.name)
        with open(path, 'w') as infile:
            str_repr = file_obj.read().decode()  # Assuming text based file
            infile.write(str_repr)
        full_url = f'{request.schema}://{request.get_host()}/{path}'
        return Response({'file': full_url}, status=201)
```

Comment: It throws this error: write() argument must be str, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to transform a text based file into a string. Let me know if you need to handle a different file type.